# Map multiple occurrences of the same JSON element to a list of objects with Codable in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, codable

My source is a JSON-fied Wordpress feed. That means, that the JSON has multiple occurrences of the same tag `<item>`.

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>Titel 1</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Titel 2</title>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I also have two structs `Channel` and `Item`. Both implement the `Codable` protocol.

**Channel**

```
struct Channel: Codable {

    // Channel name
    let title: String?

    // All items (blog entries) from the channel
    let items = [Item]()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case items = "item"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values  = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title       = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)

        let itemValues = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Item.CodingKeys, forKey: Feed.CodingKeys.items)
        items = try values.decode([Item.self], forKey: .title) // <-- Crash!!
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My problem is, that my `let items = [Item]()` will never be filled. I tried  the example from [quickbytes.io](https://www.quickbytes.io/tutorials/introduction-to-json-and-codable-in-swift-4) but it has another data structure.

In my manager, I'll call:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
try? decoder.decode(Feed.self, from: jsonData)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ...That's a Property List, not JSON...

Comment: And `JSONSerialization` ≠ `JSONDecoder`

Comment: The JSONDecoder needs a Data object as a parameter, I thought, that I need the Serializer to make a Data object and pass this into my decoder?

Comment: Well what is the type of your original data source? Is it `String`, `Data`, or what?

Comment: @Rob oh, thanks. I'll have a deeper look at it. Now, I think I understood what Alexander had pointed out.

Comment: Just to confirm, that isn't technically a property list, either. It's XML.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're converting that XML into JSON. I'd suggest you edit the question showing us what the resulting JSON looks like. But let's imagine it ended up looking like:

```
{"channel":
    [
        {"title": "Title 1"},
        {"title": "Title 2"}
    ]
}
```

In that case, you could do:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let title: String
}

struct Channel: Codable {
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "channel"
    }
}
```

And then:

```
do {
    let channel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Channel.self, from: data)
    print(channel)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But, clearly, if your JSON looks different than what I assumed above, we'd have to change the implementation accordingly. But we can't say without seeing what the JSON actually looked like.

Below, in my original answer, I show how you might parse the XML directly, bypassing the JSON-ification of the XML feed.

---

We can’t say without seeing the actual JSON, but this line is clearly wrong:

```
items = try values.decode([Item.self], forKey: .title)
```

Should probably be:

```
items = try values.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
```

Note where the `]` is, as well as the use of `.items` rather than `.title`.

Frankly, this whole `init(from:)` looks unnecessary, but it’s impossible to say without seeing what your actual JSON looks like.

—-

This is XML, not JSON. So you can use neither `JSONSerialization` nor `JSONDecoder`. So you'll probably want to use `XMLParser`:

```
let delegate = ChannelParserDelegate()
let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
parser.delegate = delegate
guard parser.parse(), let channel = delegate.channel else {
    print(parser.parserError ?? "Unknown error")
    return
}

print(channel)
```

Where

```
struct Channel {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item {
    let title: String
}
```

and

```
class ChannelParserDelegate: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    var channel: Channel?
    private var items: [Item]?
    private var currentValue: String?
    private var values: [String: Any]?

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == "channel" {
            items = []
        } else if elementName == "item" {
            values = [:]
        } else if elementName == "title" {
            currentValue = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        currentValue? += string
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "title" {
            values?[elementName] = currentValue
            currentValue = nil
        } else if elementName == "item" {
            items?.append(Item(title: values!["title"] as! String))
            values = nil
        } else if elementName == "channel" {
            channel = Channel(items: items!)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        channel = nil
        items = nil
    }
}
```

If you end up with more `Item` properties other than just `title`, then just add clauses for them like I have for `title` in `didStartElement` and `didEndElement`.

---

In the interest of full disclosure, there are WordPress plug-ins for which you can generate JSON feeds. So, you then theoretically use `JSONDecoder` (or, if you must, `JSONSerialization`). But if you don't want to mess around with tweaking your server configuration, you can use `XMLParser` in your client code, like outlined above.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I know that the feed is xml, but I do not like this format at all, that's the reason I converted into something like JSON. In my current code I use the `ObjectMapper` to map the xml -> json to son -> object. :)

Comment: If you've converted it to JSON, then I'd suggest you edit the question to include what the JSON looks like. We can't help you parse JSON if you refuse to show us what JSON you want to parse.